# Does Linear differential operator having factors commute?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $L$  is a linear differential operator that factors but has variable coefficients. Do the factors of $L$  commute?

Could someone please guide me on how to proceed in this problem?

Comment: It's better to post the operator and the DE. Most of the times it dosent commute when the coefficients are variables.

Comment: Just try it out. For instance, are $(D+x)D$ and $D(D+x)$ the same differential operator?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ok got it. But are there cases where they can commute even after variable coefficients?